# How to set frame font in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to change the font in Emacs from within a major mode. I am using Emacs 24.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I tried `set-frame-font`, like:

```
(set-frame-font "DejaVu Sans Mono-10")
```

But I get error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Font not available" #<font-spec nil nil DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono nil nil nil nil nil 10.0 nil nil nil ((:name . "DejaVu Sans Mono-10") (user-spec . "DejaVu Sans Mono-10"))>)
  internal-set-lisp-face-attribute(default :font "DejaVu Sans Mono-10" #<frame emacs-24.3@cipr064219.klientdrift.uib.no 0x116a4c0>)
```

The output of `fc-list` is:

```
fc-list | grep 'DejaVu Sans Mono'

DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold Oblique
DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Oblique
DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book
DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold
```

Comment: Your code works for me (Emacs 24.3 on Ubuntu 13.10). Did you just recently install the font, or has it been there for a while?

Comment: @Chris I have not installed any fonts at all..

Comment: If you shift-click the buffer and select "Change Buffer Font...", does DejaVu Sans Mono appear in the list of available fonts?

Comment: @Chris No it does not appear in the popup menu for `"Change Text Font"`. There are three sub menues: `"Fontset"`, `"Courier"`, and `"Misc"`. It does not appear in either of these sub menues.

Comment: Did you install Emacs from a package or from source? Is there any chance your Emacs may have been built without Xft support? Also, what is the full version number for your Emacs? Your fonts menu has different options than mine (24.3.50.1).

Comment: @Chris Yes I built Emacs from source. The full version is: `GNU Emacs 24.3.1`. How can I add Xft support?

Comment: [According to EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/XftGnuEmacs#toc9) you should include `--with-xft` when you `./configure`. If this works I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, it seems it did not work. I reinstalled Emacs now using `./configure --prefix=/scratch/emacs-24.3 --with-xft`.. However, I still get the same error message regarding `set-frame-font`

Comment: You have `libxft-dev` installed?

Comment: @Chris No. Should I install it?

Comment: It's almost certainly required to compile Emacs with Xft support. Install it, then build Emacs again with the `--with-xft` flag.

Comment: @Chris Great! It seems to work now. You can add it as an answer i fyou like and I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you've built Emacs without [Xft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xft) support, which is required if you want to use anti-aliased, TrueType, and OpenType fonts.

Here is how you can build it with Xft:

1. Install the `libxft-dev` package, which contains the required Xft headers:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxft-dev
   ```
2. Build Emacs as before, but this time [include the `--with-xft` flag in your `./configure` command](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/XftGnuEmacs#toc9).

Now your Emacs should be able to use TrueType and OpenType fonts, including DejaVu Sans Mono.